# Getx How to refresh list by using Obx

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, flutter-getx

I'm working with **ReorderableSliverList** but I have no idea how to observe the list based on my data dynamically.

Screen 1

```
ReorderableSliverList(
          delegate: ReorderableSliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                final data = controller.products[index];
                    return ItemView(data);
            },
          childCount: controller.products.length),
          onReorder: _onReorder,
        )
```

At screen2 will have a add button to call controller insert new data into list

controller

```
var products = List<Product>.empty().obs;
void add(String name) {
    if (name != '') {
      final date = DateTime.now().toIso8601String();

      ProductProvider().postProduct(name, date).then((response) {
        final data = Product(
          id: response["name"],
          name: name,
          createdAt: date,
        );
        products.add(data);
        Get.back();
      });
    } else {
      dialogError("Semua input harus terisi");
    }
  }
```

The code above need to click **Hot reload** in order to show data in screen 1 if data has changed from screen 2.
I'm trying to use Obx to make it refresh automatically but the result it still the same.

Code

```
ReorderableSliverList(
          delegate: ReorderableSliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
            final data = controller.products[index];
            return Obx(
              () => controller.products.isEmpty
                  ? Center(
                      child: Text("BELUM ADA DATA"),
                    )
                  :  ItemView(data)        
            );
          }, childCount: controller.products.length),
          onReorder: _onReorder,
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the whole **ReorderableSliverList** with **Obx** like this:

```
Obx(()=>ReorderableSliverList(
...
...
));
```